# Accessing controller from header partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I thought this would be easier to do but I haven't been able to find a solution. Basically I want my layouts/_header.html.erb file to have access to a notifications method in my users controller or even just create a new method for this partial if that's possible.

**layouts/_header.html.erb:**

```
<% if @posts_count > 0 %>
Hello
<% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb:**

```
def notifications
@posts_count = @reminder.posts.count
end
```

The header is being rendered in

**application.html.erb:**

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to declare that method as a helper method in your controller.

In your controller try adding:

```
helper_method :notifications
```

Here's the doc: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method